# Open .odt file at the end of file

Tags: libreoffice, ubuntu-mate

I have a large Tips document that I frequently edit.

Is there a way to open a LibreOffice .odt file so the cursor is at the end of the file? (Without having to scroll down to it.)

I looked here.

```
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/swriter  --help
```

3/19/19

```
 find . '!' -user $USER -ls andy@7_~/Downloads$
```

Comment: You do know that just Ctrl + end key brings you to the very end of the file?

Comment: @Jacob Vlijm Yes I do.

Answer (score 0):

To do so, open *Tools > Options > LibreOffice > User Data*, fill in the name fields and click *OK*. Save the file just to be thorough.

[image: LibreOffice Options]

Now, whenever you open a file, the insertion cursor will be at the same point as when you last closed the file. If that happens to be at the end of your document, that's where the cursor will be.

Comment: It did not work for me?

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: Please check if you have an issue with permissions. Run `find . '!' -user $USER -ls` and post the output in your question.

Comment: find . '!' -user $USER -ls
andy@7_~/Downloads$ @DK Bose

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7grm77rkec5tls4/ls.txt?dl=0

Comment: Ideally, **nothing** in your home folder should be owned by root. That's what the command detects. If a file that needs to be modified by *you* is owned by root, changes *you* try to make won't be successful.

Comment: Should I do this.  chown -R user directory/

Comment: Strangely, when I open another document, it does go to the end. :-)